# Connect a remote Supervisor Daemon to a Storm cluster in Docker Containers

Tags: docker, apache-storm

I have a cluster running Storm with docker containers in a machine that it's connected to my local network and I need to connect a remote Supervisor to it that is running in a container allocated in other machine connected to the same local network. So far, I'm able to make the nimbus node recognize the supervisor

[Storm ui capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avqav.png)

But nimbus doesn't assign task to the supervisor when a topology it's submitted. Is to be noted that when I run the supervisor inside the cluster the topology works well and task are assigned.

The configuration of the docker containing the cluster

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
    zookeeper:
        image: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
    nimbus:
        image: storm
        container_name: nimbus
        command: storm nimbus
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        links:
            - zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 6627:6627
        volumes:
            - './storm-nimbus:/theproject'
            - './logs:/logs'
            - './data:/data'
    ui:
        image: storm
        container_name: ui
        command: storm ui
        depends_on:
            - nimbus
        links:
            - nimbus
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
volumes:
    storm-nimbus:
```

The configuration of the docker containing the supervisor:

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
    supervisor:
        image: storm
        container_name: supervisor
        command: storm supervisor
        ports:
            - 6628:6628
            - 6700:6700
            - 6701:6701
            - 6702:6702
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - './logs:/logs'
            - './data:/data'
volumes:
    storm-nimbus:
```

Storm.yaml in the supervisor

```yaml
storm.zookeeper.servers: ["192.168.0.120"]
nimbus.seeds: ["192.168.0.120"]
supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
```

Nimbus' logs

```
2021-02-06 21:03:45.563 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Node Id: cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2 Total Mem: 4096.0, Used Mem: 2304.0, Available Mem: 1792.0, Total CPU: 400.0, Used CPU: 180.0, Available CPU: 220.0, fragmented: false
2021-02-06 21:03:45.564 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Setting new assignment for topology id test-1-1612641077: Assignment(master_code_dir:/data, node_host:{cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2=dfa0da54f26d}, executor_node_port:{[10, 10]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6700]), [16, 16]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6700]), [14, 14]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6701]), [12, 12]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6702]), [8, 8]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6701]), [6, 6]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6702]), [4, 4]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6700]), [2, 2]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6701]), [18, 18]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6702]), [7, 7]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6700]), [11, 11]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6701]), [5, 5]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6701]), [3, 3]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6702]), [1, 1]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6700]), [17, 17]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6701]), [15, 15]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6702]), [13, 13]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6700]), [9, 9]=NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6702])}, executor_start_time_secs:{[8, 8]=1612645425, [2, 2]=1612645425, [14, 14]=1612645425, [6, 6]=1612645425, [12, 12]=1612645425, [18, 18]=1612645425, [4, 4]=1612645425, [10, 10]=1612645425, [16, 16]=1612645425, [11, 11]=1612645425, [5, 5]=1612645425, [17, 17]=1612645425, [3, 3]=1612645425, [9, 9]=1612645425, [15, 15]=1612645425, [1, 1]=1612645425, [7, 7]=1612645425, [13, 13]=1612645425}, worker_resources:{NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6700])=WorkerResources(mem_on_heap:768.0, mem_off_heap:0.0, cpu:60.0, shared_mem_on_heap:0.0, shared_mem_off_heap:0.0, resources:{onheap.memory.mb=768.0, cpu.pcore.percent=60.0, offheap.memory.mb=0.0}, shared_resources:{}), NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6702])=WorkerResources(mem_on_heap:768.0, mem_off_heap:0.0, cpu:60.0, shared_mem_on_heap:0.0, shared_mem_off_heap:0.0, resources:{onheap.memory.mb=768.0, cpu.pcore.percent=60.0, offheap.memory.mb=0.0}, shared_resources:{}), NodeInfo(node:cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2, port:[6701])=WorkerResources(mem_on_heap:768.0, mem_off_heap:0.0, cpu:60.0, shared_mem_on_heap:0.0, shared_mem_off_heap:0.0, resources:{onheap.memory.mb=768.0, cpu.pcore.percent=60.0, offheap.memory.mb=0.0}, shared_resources:{})}, total_shared_off_heap:{}, owner:storm)
2021-02-06 21:03:55.746 o.a.s.n.AssignmentDistributionService pool-26-thread-1 [ERROR] Exception to create supervisor client for node cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.UnknownHostException: dfa0da54f26d
2021-02-06 21:03:56.053 o.a.s.s.b.r.LogReporter timer [WARN] add supervisor cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2  to blacklist. The bad slot history of supervisors is : [{cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2=[6700, 6701, 6702]}, {cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2=[6700, 6701, 6702]}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2=[6700, 6701, 6702]}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2=[6700, 6701, 6702]}, {}, {}]
2021-02-06 21:03:56.054 o.a.s.s.b.BlacklistScheduler timer [INFO] Supervisors [cc81d1e3-672f-40cc-9e94-42a5d2b06f0b-172.18.0.2] are blacklisted.
```

Supervisor's logs

```
021-02-06 21:05:42.664 o.a.s.d.s.t.SynchronizeAssignments Thread-4 [ERROR] Get assignments from master exception
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [192.168.0.120]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:250) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:179) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:138) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.timer.SynchronizeAssignments.getAssignmentsFromMaster(SynchronizeAssignments.java:152) [storm-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.timer.SynchronizeAssignments.run(SynchronizeAssignments.java:82) [storm-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.event.EventManagerImp$1.run(EventManagerImp.java:49) [storm-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
2021-02-06 21:05:45.662 o.a.s.u.NimbusClient timer [WARN] Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from 192.168.0.120. will retry with a different seed host.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.UnknownHostException: 14e67ed3493f
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:108) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:69) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:80) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:234) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:179) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:138) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.timer.ReportWorkerHeartbeats.reportWorkerHeartbeats(ReportWorkerHeartbeats.java:98) [storm-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.timer.ReportWorkerHeartbeats.run(ReportWorkerHeartbeats.java:48) [storm-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.StormTimer$1.run(StormTimer.java:110) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.StormTimer$StormTimerTask.run(StormTimer.java:226) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.UnknownHostException: 14e67ed3493f
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.retryNext(TBackoffConnect.java:59) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:51) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:98) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.UnknownHostException: 14e67ed3493f
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:91) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:101) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:98) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 14e67ed3493f
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:91) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:101) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:98) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Same error for me - did you make any progress?